# undefined method 'map' for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dictionary, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined

I have a Rails 4 application. I have a search function with a select field. Now I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodeError: undefined method 'map' for "5":String: select * from users inner join user_texts on users.id = user_id where text_id = ?
```

Here's view:

```
<% form_tag user_path do
 <% select_tag :text_id, Option_from_collection_for_select(text.all, :id, :name, params[:text_id]), include_blank: true %>
<%= button_to '#', class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
<% t(:find) %>
<% end %>
```

Here's controller:

```
def index
  if params[:text_id].present?
     @users = User.search params[:text_id]
  end
  @users = User.all
end
```

Here's model:

```
def self.search(text_id)
find_by_sql("select * from users inner join user_texts on users.id = user_id where text_id = ?
", text_id)
end
```

When I do this, it works perfect:

```
select * from users inner join user_texts on users.id = user_id where text_id = 5
```

Comment: A couple issues: 1) can you post more of the stack trace after the error message? 2) `Option_from_collection_for_select` should most likely be `options_from_collection_for_select`, 3) `text.all` should probably be `Text.all`, and 4) Your `@users` variable will always be `User.all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to this

```
def self.search(text_id)
  User.joins(:user_texts).where("text_id = ?", text_id)
end
```

Two reasons why you should change

1. This is more rails-y way of doing it
2. find_by_sql doesn't work well with query placeholders

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is perfectly fine and recommended, but sometimes you have to fetch from a raw sql query. And the error above is we need to use square brackets `[` instead of round `(` ones. Check out the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql)

So this should have worked.

```
def self.search(text_id)
   find_by_sql ["select * from users inner join user_texts on users.id = user_id where text_id = ?
   ", text_id ]
end
```