# Undefined method `map' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I want to email users every time a new treatment that is under the category they are interested in is added.

I have a join table `interests_users` which is holds a `user_id` and a `interest_id`. Treatments has a variable called `category` which is used to compare against interests.

This is what the create block in my treatments controller looks like.

```
def create
  @treatment = Treatment.new(treatment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @treatment.save
      interest = Interest.find_by(name: @treatment.category)
      if interest
        User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users
                    INNER JOIN interests_users ON clients.id =    interests_users.client_id
                    WHERE interests_users.interest_id = ?", interest.id).each do |user|
          Bestevermailer.treatmentNotification(user, @treatment).deliver
        end
      end

      format.html { redirect_to @treatment, notice: 'Treatment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @treatment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @treatment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Full Trace

```
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:289:in `exec_query'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:355:in `select'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:68:in `block in select_all'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:83:in `cache_sql'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:68:in `select_all'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
app/controllers/treatments_controller.rb:72:in `block in create'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:212:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/treatments_controller.rb:68:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: where are you using `map`? Please post exact error trace.

Comment: Posted the full trace in OP

Comment: I'm assuming the 7th line in you code snippet is line 72, am I correct? Can you confirm in the console if User.find_by_sql("...").each{|user| user.id} gives the same error?

Comment: That's not the full stack trace. It is missing at least the first line - the one with the exact error message and line number in which the error occurred.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz Yes that is the correct line (72). I'm not sure exactly how to run that command directly into the console?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa how to resolve the error and have a working query that performs the task I outlined in the op

Answer (score 1):

Try re-framing your query. Here:

```
User.joins('INNER JOIN interests_users ON clients.id = interests_users.client_id').where("interests_users.interest_id = ?", interest.id)
```

[As per a similar SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22153180/3035830):

> `find_by_sql` doesn't work well with query placeholders

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that query gave me the error 'SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: clients.id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN interests_users ON clients.id = interests_users.client_id WHERE (interests_users.interest_id = 1)'

Comment: I just copied your Inner Join query. You may need to fix that yourself as I dont know your table structures.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you explain to me what rails is referring to when it gives a 'map' error?

Comment: as per my understanding `find_by_sql` method is internally mapping results. Since we just discovered the join query is incorrect, (most probably) therefore `map` is encountering `nil` instead of an Array object. Hence the error. Fixing join statement, may itself solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[`find_by_sql` expects](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql) an array as a parameter:

```
User.find_by_sql([
    "SELECT * FROM users
       INNER JOIN interests_users 
       ON clients.id = interests_users.client_id
       WHERE interests_users.interest_id = ?",
     interest.id]).each do |user|
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am getting an error relating to the query and its tables because I have gotten the query logic wrong. Ugh I hate querys...